# ClojureScript extern 'on' event

Tags: google-closure-compiler, clojurescript

I'm trying to use Twitter Bootstrap's modal dialog jQuery plugin with ClojureScript, which works fine without advanced optimizations, but when Google Closure munges method names, the `on` method becomes `za`.

I've been trying to protect `on` from being munged by using an externs file, but so far no luck creating a definition that fixes this. Tips?

Answer (score 1):

What finally worked was:

```
var jQuery;
jQuery.fn = {
  on: function() {}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

with advanced you can either use goog.exportSymbol or window['object']['on'] = object['on']

Comment: goog.exportSymbol would have to be used from within bootstrap-modal.js, no? Also, using `window['object']['on'] = object['on']` gives warnings that using the name 'window' does nothing in an externs file.